# How to change animation color on mouseon and mouseout?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm building a theme switcher so when you hover something, it changes the color.

It works.

Now, I want to add animation to it, how can I do it?

I know I need a function that does that, but not sure how I can start with it.

Here is the CodePen: https://codepen.io/Aurelian/pen/djYLxx?editors=0010

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="organic-body" data-color="#1f2f1e" style="background-color: rgb(31, 51, 34);">
<div class="container">

  <h5>Hover to change color</h5>

  <div class="organic-list">
  <a href="#" class="organic-card js-organic-card-hover" data-color="red">
    <h2>Color red</h2>
  </a>

  <a href="#" class="organic-card js-organic-card-hover" data-color="blue">
    <h2>Color blue</h2>
  </a>

  <a href="#" class="organic-card js-organic-card-hover" data-color="green">
    <h2>Color green</h2>
  </a>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Here is the JS:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

  // Select each item
  var organicBody = document.querySelector(".organic-body"),
      organicList = document.querySelector(".organic-list"),
      organicCard = document.querySelectorAll(".organic-card");

      organicCard.forEach(function(item) {
        item.addEventListener('mouseover', function(event) {
          var itemDataColor = item.getAttribute('data-color');
          organicBody.style.backgroundColor = itemDataColor;

        })
        item.addEventListener('mouseout', function(event) {
          var bodyColor = organicBody.getAttribute('data-color');
          organicBody.style.backgroundColor = bodyColor;
        });
      })


      // Set interval on how long you want it to animate
      // Convert color to RGB

      function animateColorChange() {

         setTimeout(function(){ 

         }, 3000);

      }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply modify the CSS to include a `transition` property, like so:

```
.organic-body {
  height: 100vh;  
  transition: background-color 1000ms;
}
```

This means any time the `background-color` property changes, it should transition gradually over 1000ms

**EDIT**

If you really must use JS (and I strongly advise against it), this is roughly what you need to do

```js
let frames = 60; // The number of frames. The lower the number, the choppier the transition
let duration = 1000; // How long the transition should take
let from = [255, 0, 0]; // RGB values
let to = [0, 0, 255]; // RGB values

// Calculate the differences between the two
let diff = to.map((v, idx) => v - from[idx]);
// Divide that by the number of frames to find out what change should be made in each frame
let frameChange = diff.map(v => v / frames);

let elem = document.getElementById('example');
let step = 1;


function tick() {
    from = from.map((v, idx) => v + frameChange[idx]);
    elem.style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${from[0]}, ${from[1]}, ${from[2]})`;
    step++;
    if (step <= frames) {
        setTimeout(tick, duration / frames)
    }
}

tick()
```

```css
div#example {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="example">
</div>
```

Comment: That works too. What about vanilla JS? I'm trying to learn JS so doing this in CSS doesn't help : p

Comment: It'll be really tough. You'll need to know the RGB value first, instead of the color name. I think you'd be much better off using the built in capabilities of CSS

Comment: Yes, you're right, it's just that I'm not learning CSS, I'm master at it. I'm trying to learn data structures and JavaScript so I can create something like that when I'm creating an app where there is no CSS. I'm sure I need to get the RGBA in different variables and then somehow loop the value with some second or soemthing like that?

Comment: You will need to get the RGB value, and find the difference between the currrent value and your desired value for each of RGB. Then, you need to divide that by the number of steps you want the transition to be (maybe 10 steps, each 100ms apart to make 1 second), and go from there

Comment: @AurelianSpodarec I've updated my answer to show a basic JS solution, assuming you have RGB values already

Comment: So what about transperancy, opacity?